# Click function at each divs

Tags: jquery

I have some divs with same class but different id and also a loader image.. check my code:

```
<div class="addme" id="1">
<span class="loader">
<img class="addloader" src="loaders/addloader.gif" width="32" height="32" style="display:none;" />
</span>
</div>

<div class="addme" id="2">
<span class="loader">
<img class="addloader" src="loaders/addloader.gif" width="32" height="32" style="display:none;" />
</span>
</div>

<div class="addme" id="3">
<span class="loader">
<img class="addloader" src="loaders/addloader.gif" width="32" height="32" style="display:none;" />
</span>
</div>
```

I tried this with no luck..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
$('.addme').click(function(){
$('.addloader').fadeIn("slow");
}); 
});
</script>
```

So how is it possible when click on each div to display the loader image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the `addloader` element which is inside the clicked `addme` element, so restrict your search scope using `find()` like

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.addme').click(function () {
        $(this).find('.addloader').fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vGD65/)

Answer (score 3):

use `this` reference (current clicked element) and `find()` to get that particular loader image inside it.

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.addme').click(function(){
     $(this).find('.addloader').fadeIn("slow");
   }); 
 });
</script>
```

and it is better to avoid numbers as  id .. instead use string..